# CSS anchor style for images

Tags: css

i set up a style for all my links but the problem is that any anchor that has an image obviously will have the same style.

is there any way i can overwrite the style for the images without having to apply a class to all the images that removes that style?

Answer (score 3):

```
a img {
 /* alternative style for hyperlinked images */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend rewriting your code to not use images but for your links with images just use clickable divs displayed as blocks.

```
<div id="x"><a href=".." class="y"></a></div>


.y {
display: block;
}

#x {
width:..;
height:..;
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-image:url(IMGPATHHERE!);
}

#x:hover {
width:..;
height:..;
padding:0;
margin:0;
background-image:url(THEHOVERIMGHERE!);
cursor:hand;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no CSS selector which will capture `<a>` elements which contain only an `<img>` element.  You will need to apply a class either at design-time or at run-time with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery qualified selectors $('a:has(img)')